# Scroll down when I right click with two fingers in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

Everytime I want to right click something, the page always scrolls down a bit first before actually doing the right click action and it's quite annoying. How can I fix this?

Touchpad model: `Alps PS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad`

Comment: Please post the model of the touchpad.

Comment: Name="AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad"